# Primefaces: Growl is displayed without the icon

Tags: primefaces

When growl is displayed (in the example below, showing the message 'Chart updated') the icon does not appear. There are no error messages in the console. This happens in a single page, the rest of the application works fine. What could be wrong?

[image]

UPDATE: the page is loaded as an iframe

This is how the growl is declared:

```
<p:growl life="2000" id="messages" for="msg1" showDetail="true"/>
```

and the java:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("Chart updated", "");
context.addMessage("msg1", fm);
```

Comment: Post the way you're sending the message.

Comment: Can you try using: `FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Chart updated", "");`

Comment: That did the trick; post the answer so I can accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `Severity` of your `FacesMessage`. You can use the following constructor:

```
FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
  "Message header", "Message detail")
```

Cheers.